# Line separator to not be used before or after page breaks

Tags: page-breaking

I have created a horizontal line in order to separate elements in my document. My question is how can I set it to not be used when it happens to be in the top of the page (i.e. right after a page break) or at the bottom of it (i.e. right before a page break)?

```
\newcommand{\Sep}
{
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \begin{center}
    \rule{3cm}{1.5pt}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
}
```

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Sep}
{
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{center}
\rule{3cm}{1.5pt}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}
}

\begin{document}

Text

\Sep

More text


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example people can compile.

Comment: @cfr I edited my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\cleaders` after `\vskip`. It disappears when the breaking point is this `\vskip`. They are classical TeX primitives:

```
\def\Sep{\vskip 0.5cm
   \cleaders\hbox to\hsize{\hss\vrule height1.5pt width3cm\hss}\vskip 2pt
   \nobreak\vskip 0.5cm \relax
}
```

Comment: +1. I was hoping someone would post a `\cleaders`-based answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Note that at the bottom of the page I check to see if there is enough room for `\Sep` (`2\parskip+1cm+1.5pt`).  If not, I force a `\newpage` to keep any following text on the next page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\tempdima}

\newcommand{\Sep}%
{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
  \pgfextracty{\tempdima}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointorigin}%
    {\pgfpointanchor{current page text area}{north}}}
  \global\tempdima=\tempdima}%
\ifdim\tempdima<\baselineskip
\else\ifdim\tempdima>\dimexpr\textheight-2\parskip-1cm-1.5pt\relax\newpage
  \else
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \begin{center}
    \rule{3cm}{1.5pt}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
  \fi
\fi}

\begin{document}
\Sep
\lipsum[1]
\Sep
\lipsum[2]
\rule{1pt}{20\baselineskip}\par
\Sep
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```